# Parameterizing a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

The question I was asked goes like this:

> The part of the hyperboloid $5x^2 − 5y^2 − z^2 = 5$ that lies in front of the yz-plane. Let x, y, and z be in terms of u and/or v. Find a parametric representation for the surface.

So, by fixing $x$ as a constant $u$, I find that the slice is an ellipse which can be parameterized as $y = \sqrt{\frac{5u^2-5}{5}}\cos{v}$ and $z = \sqrt{5u^2-5}\sin{v}$, where $u$ ranges from $1$ to infinity, and $v$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$.

However, I was told that this is not the correct parameterization. The correct answer is

$$
\begin{align*}
x&=\sqrt{1+u^2+\frac{1}{5}v^2} \\
y&= u \\
z&= v
\end{align*}
$$

I believe that this is just another way of parameterizing the same surface, and I don't see why my answer is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Both of these are a bit confusing. Both x and -x are solutions... that is ignored in second parametrization ...

Comment: @sanjab - I think this is because we only care about the part that lies in front of the yz-plane.

Comment: Ah. Yes you are correct. Missed that part

Comment: Your parametrization looks correct

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Does your definition of parametrization require injectivity?

Comment: @GitGud The question doesn't explicitly require it to be one-to-one but it might be the reason since this was graded by a computer.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 If one has to deal with injecvity it becomes tricky (if not impossible) to use your parametrization. In any case the function you suggest does map the desired surface. I proved so below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret being 'in front of the $yz$-plane' as the first coordinate being non-negative, thus the surface $S$ in question $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3\colon x\ge 0\land 5x^2 − 5y^2 − z^2 = 5\}$.

It can easily be proved that this set equals $\left\{\left(\sqrt{1+y^2+\dfrac{z^2}5}, y,z\right)\colon y,z\in \mathbb R\right\}$, therefore $S=\vec r\left[\mathbb R^2\right]$, where and $\vec r\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3, (u,v)\mapsto \left(\sqrt{1+u^2+\dfrac{v^2}5}, u,v\right)$. So this $\vec r$ is certainly a suitable candidate for parametrization (you need to check that it satisfies the other properties for being one). In my mind this is the most natural option.

You suggest taking $\vec s\colon D\to \mathbb R^3, (\rho,\theta)\mapsto \left(\rho, \sqrt{\rho ^2-1}\cos(\theta), \sqrt 5\sqrt{\rho^2-1}\sin(\theta)\right)$, where $D=[1,+\infty[\times [0,2\pi[$.

I don't see how to make any variation of this parametrization become injective (I think it's not possible) and that might be why yours was marked wrong.

Anyway, I'll prove that $S=\vec s[D]$. The inclusion $\supseteq$ is the easy one. I'll help out with the other one.

Let $(x,y,z)\in S$. Due to $x^2=1+y^2+\dfrac{z^2}5$ it's easy to conclude that $x\ge 1$.

One wishes to find $(\rho, \theta)\in [1,+\infty[\times[0,2\pi[$ such that $(x,y,z)= \left(\rho, \sqrt{\rho ^2-1}\cos(\theta), \sqrt 5\sqrt{\rho^2-1}\sin(\theta)\right)$.

If $x=1$, then $y=0=z$ and $(x,y,z)=\vec s(1,\theta)$, for any $\theta$.

Suppose $x>1$. If such $(\rho, \theta)$ exists, necessarily $\rho =x$ and $y=\sqrt{\rho ^2-1}\cos(\theta)$. This ensues the equality $\cos(\theta)=\dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$. So it's necessary to check that $-1\leq \dfrac{y}{x^2-1} \leq 1$ or equivalently that$\dfrac{y^2}{x^2-1}\leq 1$, and this in fact holds because $x^2=1+y^2+\dfrac{z^2}5$.

So take $\theta=\arccos\left(\dfrac y{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)\lor \theta=2\pi-\arccos\left(\dfrac y{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)$, depending on whether you're in $[0,\pi]$ or $[\pi, 2\pi]$.

All that is left is to check that this choice of $(\rho, \theta)$ works. I'll check the first one.

In fact 
$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align} \vec s(\rho, \theta)&=\left(\rho, \sqrt{\rho ^2-1}\cos(\theta), \sqrt 5\sqrt{\rho^2-1}\sin(\theta)\right)\\
&=\left(x, \sqrt{x ^2-1}\cos\left(\arccos\left(\dfrac y{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)\right), \sqrt 5\sqrt{x^2-1}\sin\left(\arccos\left(\dfrac y{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)\right)\right)\\
&=\left(x,y,\sqrt 5\sqrt{x^2-1}\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac y{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)^2}\right)\\
&=\left(x,y,\sqrt 5\cancel{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2-1}{\cancel{x^2-1}}-\dfrac{y^2}{\cancel{x^2-1}}}\right)\\
&=\left(x,y,\sqrt 5\sqrt{y^2+\frac{z^2}5-y^2}\right)\\
&=(x,y,z).
\end{align}
$$

To ensure that you get an appropriate $z$ just choose one of the two possible values of $\theta$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the detailed proof! Took me quite a while to read through it.

Comment: You're welcome. Usually in this context such set equality proofs are unnecessary in the sense that whoever marks the problems will not care, they're more interested in knowing if you can visualize what's going on. I myself like to prove the details, specially the geometrical ones.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, conic sections are parametrized best with some kind of cylindrical or spherical coordinate transformation.  Given $$5x^2 - 5y^2 - z^2 = 5, \quad x > 0,$$ this suggests a cylindrical parametrization with $$(y,z) = (u \cos v, \sqrt{5} u \sin v),$$ which easily gives $$5x^2 = 5 + 5y^2 + z^2 = 5 + 5u^2 (\cos^2 v + \sin^2 v) = 5(u^2+1),$$ or $$x = \sqrt{u^2 + 1},$$ where we take the positive square root since we were asked to provide the portion of the surface "in front of" the $yz$-plane (which I assume to mean $x > 0$).  Thus one parametrization is $$\begin{align*} x &= \sqrt{u^2 + 1}, \\ y &= u \cos v, \\ z &= \sqrt{5}u \sin v, \end{align*}$$ for $u \in [0,\infty)$ and $v \in [0, 2\pi)$.  Now, the above parametrization works just fine, but we can make it a little nicer and consider $$\begin{align*} x &= \sec u, \\ y &= \tan u \cos v, \\ z &= \sqrt{5} \tan u \sin v, \end{align*}$$ for $u \in [0,\pi/2)$, $v \in [0,2\pi)$, which gives the same result:  this was motivated by the familiar trigonometric identity $$\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2 \theta.$$  Clearly, we can see that parametrizations are not unique, and that in general, infinitely many legitimate parametrizations of the same surface are possible.

Comment: I see, parameterizations indeed are not unique.